# SELECT de 2 FK na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

Tendo em vista este cenario:

Imagine um cenário no ramo da oceanografia, onde a tabela_A , além da chave primaria, precise guardar também a direção do vento(dir_vento) e a direção da ondulação(dir_ondulacao). Sabendo que a tabela_ventos(id_vento, desc_vento) possui todas as direções possíveis, e ambos os campos dir_vento e dir_ondulacao também são ventos, seria possível que eles guardassem a id_vento, para futuramente eu resgatar a dsc_vento da tabela vento a partir deles, ou seja, seriam os campos dir_vento e dir_ondulacao chaves estrangeiras da tabela_ventos.

como faço para executar o select?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve fazer dois relacionamentos com a mesma tabela, apelidando-as de forma distinta, desta forma:

```
SELECT A.Id, V.Dsc_Vento As Dir_Vento, O.Dsc_Vento As Dir_Ondulacao
  FROM tabela_A A
 INNER JOIN tabela_ventos V ON V.Id_Vento = A.Dir_Vento
 INNER JOIN tabela_ventos O ON O.Id_Vento = A.Dir_Ondulacao;
```

Espero ter conseguido ajudar.

Comment: ...e o perguntador some ...